# Aloccating free space

Tags: partitioning

Is there a way to allocate this free space in the sda6? Thx.

"não alocada" = "non allocated"

[image: gparted]

Answer (score 0):

There is. You have to boot from live USB/CD and open GParted as root:

```
sudo gparted &
```

and then select `sda6` and Resize/Move to enlarge the partition in to the unallocated space.

**Please backup everything before you do that.**

Also, I'm not sure what is in `sda5` (the thing preceding `sda6`) be careful.

More information can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/).